# JMeter - Groovy script performing wrong calculations

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have 2 csv files

File 1:

```
       Name                   Start_Time
eml-alertservice               19:42:12
eml-redis                      19:42:12
eml-fluentd                    19:42:12
eml-kube-prometheus-stack      19:42:13
mwl-query-service              19:42:13
eml-grafana                    19:42:13
entity-management-service      19:42:14
snomed-service                 19:44:04
nuevo-dcm-services-wado        19:44:05
eis-common-postgres            19:45:43
```

File 2:

```
   OS         K3s        Duration
18:10:06    18:10:45     39 secs
18:53:38    18:54:17     39 secs
20:03:19    20:03:58     39 secs
16:27:45    16:28:51     66 secs
19:38:12    19:39:12     60 secs
```

From File 1, Except the 1st row capture whole of the data. From File 2, extract only the 2nd column from last row. Write these data into File 3. In File 3, subtract column 3 from column 2 (These are time values) and display the results (time in secs) in column 4. Overall, File 3 should look like

File 3:

```
         Name                 Start_Time            K3s         Duration
eml-alertservice               19:42:12           19:39:12      60 secs
eml-redis                      19:42:12           19:39:12      60 secs
eml-fluentd                    19:42:12           19:39:12      60 secs
eml-kube-prometheus-stack      19:42:13           19:39:12      61 secs
mwl-query-service              19:42:13           19:39:12      61 secs
eml-grafana                    19:42:13           19:39:12      61 secs
entity-management-service      19:42:14           19:39:12      62 secs
snomed-service                 19:44:04           19:39:12      292 secs
nuevo-dcm-services-wado        19:44:05           19:39:12      293 secs
eis-common-postgres            19:45:43           19:39:12      391 secs
```

The sample code below works fine in most cases:

```
def time = (new File('file2.csv').readLines().last() =~ /(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/)[1][1]

def file1 = new File('file1.csv').readLines()

def names = file1.drop(1).collect { line -> (line =~ /([a-z\-\_]+)/)[0][1] }
def times = file1.drop(1).collect { line -> (line =~ /(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/)[0][1] }

def file3 = new File('file3.csv')

file3 << 'Name' << '\t' << 'Start_Time' << '\t' << 'K3s' << '\t' << 'Duration' << System.getProperty('line.separator')

names.eachWithIndex { name, index ->

    def endTime = Date.parse('hh:mm:ss', times.get(index) as String)
    def startTime = Date.parse('hh:mm:ss', time as String)
    def delta = (endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000 + ' secs'
    file3 << name << '\t' << times.get(index) << '\t' << time << '\t' << delta << System.getProperty('line.separator')
}
```

But in a certain condition, it works differently (displays unexpected results). For eg.

File 1 contains

```
         Name                 Start_Time
auto-delete-service            11:57:18
workitem-management            12:02:25
eml-fluentd                    12:08:32
mwl-query-service              12:08:41
ian-scu-dcm-services           12:09:37
worklist-management            12:09:45
snomed-service                 12:09:45
eml-loki                       12:10:59
eml-api-gateway                12:11:20
eml-kibana                     12:12:28
eml-redis                      12:12:30
eisflowmanager                 12:12:42
eml-alertservice               12:12:49
transformer                    12:12:53
preferences-service            12:13:32
eml-device-registry            12:13:41
eml-elasticsearch              12:13:49
eml-kube-prometheus-stack      12:13:49
coreload-bootstrap-service     12:13:50
uid-dcm-services               12:13:50
eml-grafana                    12:14:06
eis-common-postgres            12:14:21
eisrabbitmq                    12:14:38
```

File 2 has

```
  OS          K3s        Duration
18:10:06    18:10:45     39 secs
18:53:38    18:54:17     39 secs
20:03:19    20:03:58     39 secs
17:56:39    17:57:40     61 secs
18:25:38    18:26:18     40 secs
18:00:12    18:01:07     55 secs
19:22:47    19:23:42     55 secs
11:53:33    11:54:28     55 secs
18:19:01    18:19:56     55 secs
12:14:12    12:15:07     55 secs
12:30:19    12:31:17     58 secs
14:20:51    14:21:46     55 secs
15:45:02    15:45:57     55 secs
16:52:38    16:53:36     58 secs
10:32:45    10:33:42     57 secs
11:56:15    11:57:13     58 secs
```

File 3 results come as

```
      Name                   Start_Time    K3s      Duration
auto-delete-service           11:57:18   11:57:13   5 secs
workitem-management           12:02:25   11:57:13   -42888 secs
eml-fluentd                   12:08:32   11:57:13   -42521 secs
mwl-query-service             12:08:41   11:57:13   -42512 secs
ian-scu-dcm-services          12:09:37   11:57:13   -42456 secs
worklist-management           12:09:45   11:57:13   -42448 secs
snomed-service                12:09:45   11:57:13   -42448 secs
eml-loki                      12:10:59   11:57:13   -42374 secs
eml-api-gateway               12:11:20   11:57:13   -42353 secs
eml-kibana                    12:12:28   11:57:13   -42285 secs
eml-redis                     12:12:30   11:57:13   -42283 secs
eisflowmanager                12:12:42   11:57:13   -42271 secs
eml-alertservice              12:12:49   11:57:13   -42264 secs
transformer                   12:12:53   11:57:13   -42260 secs
preferences-service           12:13:32   11:57:13   -42221 secs
eml-device-registry           12:13:41   11:57:13   -42212 secs
eml-elasticsearch             12:13:49   11:57:13   -42204 secs
eml-kube-prometheus-stack     12:13:49   11:57:13   -42204 secs
coreload-bootstrap-service    12:13:50   11:57:13   -42203 secs
uid-dcm-services              12:13:50   11:57:13   -42203 secs
eml-grafana                   12:14:06   11:57:13   -42187 secs
eis-common-postgres           12:14:21   11:57:13   -42172 secs
eisrabbitmq                   12:14:38   11:57:13   -42155 secs
```

In the above results, calculations are going wrong somewhere. When the 2nd and 3rd column values are of 12 and 11 hours respectively. This bug was noticed. It works perfect for other values.

Kindly help me in fixing this bug. Thanks for your support.

Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `hh` to `HH` in your script

As per [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation:

- `h` - Hour in am/pm (1-12)
- `H` - Hour in day (0-23)

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)